# Recording H264 in Web Browser, on Android

Tags: javascript, android, h.264, mediarecorder, google-chrome-android

I have to record a `canvas` element on a web page, using `MediaRecorder` or similar APIs, and send chunks to the a server which generates a playable live HLS playlist. I have to NOT re-encode the video segments on the server, as this should use the minimum amount of resources.

At this time I am using MediaRecorder API, with this mime type: `video/webm;codecs=h264`, which doesn't require re-encoding on the server, just changing the container. On the server side I am using `ffmpeg` to generate the HLS playlist. This is working great while broadcasting using Google Chrome or Chromium on computer. But on the latest version of Google Chrome for Android this is not working. It seems `H264` codec is not implemented yet on Chrome for Android.

What can I do as I can't re-encode the video on the server?

PS: I don't need a wide browser support, as the user can switch to the browser I recommend.

Is there any Android web browser supporting `H264`? Or, are there other available JavaScript APIs supporting `H264`? Or, is there anything I can do to be able to use H264 on Google Chrome for Android?

Thank you!